# Make Logitech script alt tab

Tags: random, lua, logitech

Trying to get my random mouse clicker script to Alt tab randomly to another window and follow the first random click, then randomly alt tab back. This is the script im using currently.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
if  IsMouseButtonPressed(5)then
   repeat
   PressMouseButton(3)
   Sleep(math.random(2000, 940000))
   ReleaseMouseButton(3)
    until IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
end
end
end
```

Also its not the end of the world but i cannot shut this script off, with mouse button 4 which is what i wrote it to do. im fairly new to LUA so excuse my noobness. Thanks.

I keep getting script errors when adding another press function

Answer (score 0):

The script checks button4 state very rarely - you should keep button4 pressed for 940 seconds to be sure the script turned off.
To be more responsive, the script should run `wait-a-bit + check-button4` loop:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
 if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
  if IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
   repeat
    PressMouseButton(3)
    local tm = GetRunningTime() + math.random(2000, 940000)
    repeat
     Sleep(10)
    until GetRunningTime() > tm or IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
    ReleaseMouseButton(3)
   until IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
  end
 end
end
```

I don't see any attempt to Alt tab simulation in your script.
Post your code.